# Why an user with the 'read' role on the database cannot list the collections?

Tags: java, mongodb

Given a normal user ('simpleROUser', only with the 'read' role on the database), it is throwing error when attempting to list collections.
The error message is:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 13 (Unauthorized): 'not authorized on wmMonitoring to execute command { listCollections: 1, cursor: {}, $db: "wmMonitoring", ...' on server xxxxxxx:27001. The full response is {"operationTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1614169303, "i": 1}}, "ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "not authorized on wmMonitoring to execute command { listCollections: 1, cursor: {}, $db: \"wmMonitoring\", ...
```

However, changing only the user credentials to one with 'root' role, it works (lists all the collections under the database 'wmMonitoring'.

I've checked the 'simpleROUser' privileges, the 'listCollections' is there.

```
rs-dev-00:PRIMARY> grants = db.getUser( "simpleROUser", { showCredentials: true, showPrivileges: true, showAuthenticationRestrictions: true } )
rs-dev-00:PRIMARY> grants.user
simpleROUser
rs-dev-00:PRIMARY> grants.inheritedPrivileges
[
        {
                "resource" : {
                        "db" : "wmISMonitoring",
                        "collection" : ""
                },
                "actions" : [
                        ...
                        "listCollections",
                        ...
                ]
        },
        ...
]
rs-dev-00:PRIMARY>
```

So... what am I missing?

More info:

- MongoDB server: Percona distribution, v4.4.1-3
- Mongo Java Driver:  v4.2.1

Comment: Does the `listCollections` work from the `mongo` shell for that user?

Answer (score 0):

Found th issue.
In Brazilan Portuguese, this is also referred as "dedo gordo".
There was a typo in the grant: the actual database name is wmMonitoring.

Once the database name (in the grant command) has fixed, everything else worked.